# Right Stack Exchange site for effort estimation question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, stackexchange.com

I have a effort estimation related question.  Which Stack Exchange site should I use?

Comment: Effort estimation... of what? I don't know that effort estimation is itself a specific topic of any particular Stack Exchange site, so it would help to identify what kind of effort you're estimating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My take would be that like shopping recommendations, questions asking for an estimate for a programming project are not suitable on any of the sites. It's impossible to make a good estimate on anything without intimately  knowing both the project, and the people who will do the work. This is by definition way too localized for a general Q&A site.

Questions about *how to make an estimate* - about methods, customs, and general pitfalls in estimating a project - may be suitable on Stack Overflow or - more often - the new [programmers Stack Exchange site](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Comment: It will be six to eight weeks anyway.

Comment: I agree with you.  I am only looking for key considerations specific for certain platorms like Android and iPhone (Some of the considerations all of us know are the number of input fields / validation, number of buttons, etc)  Thanks.